# How to find which field/attribute is not atomic?

Tags: database, normalization

This question could be off topic but I still want to know because I searched but failed to find the solution.

```
Enrollment (StudentID , courseID , course_Instructor , Student_Name ,
Student_Degree , Student_ADD , course_Name , Instructor_Name ,
Instructor_Office , Grade)
```

---

**• First Normal Form:**
Enrollment relation is not in the first Normal Form because the Attribute
Student_Degree is not Atomic.

1) Can any one tell me why `Student_Degree` is not atomic? and why just `Student_Degree` ?

2) The second little question is that in which Normal Form we define PRIMARY KEY ?

3) As I'm new to normalization, is there any way to find is my NORMALIZED tables are correct or not?

Comment: It is not just `Student_Degree`; that is just an example.

Comment: @GordonLinoff how I can find which attribute is atomic or not? and can you read 2, 3 question too please?

Comment: It was long time ago when I studied 1,2,3-NFs. BTW the main thing is to try to split your table to several tables like: (StudentID, StudentName) is Ok but (StudentID, StudentName, CourseID) is wrong because one student can to visit several courses, so it should be two relations (StudentID, StudentName) and (StudentID, StudentCourse). Same with (CourseID, CourseInstructor) - I hope that if one instructor will take vacation that whole course was not interrupted at all. And so on. Good luck in your studying.

Comment: @Abelisto thanks, I just want to ask is there any way to find, is the given table is in normalize form or not? I used common sense to normalize and split the tables into many. I just want to clear is that fine or could be more split in better way?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not provide more info then schoolbooks/tutorials about DB theory does. Just think in categories of objects/attributes/relations. For your example objects are: Student, Course, Instructor, Office etc.

Comment: BTW [wikipedia describes the first normal form (FNF, 1NF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) absolutely clear. About your question: one student can have several degrees - it is not atomic; one student can have several courses - it is not atomic; one instructor can have several offices - it is nit atomic. And so on.

Comment: PS: One person (student, instructor) can have only one name (full name) or birthday - it is atomic :) Have fun in your studying.

Comment: @Abelisto thanks. I have another confusion. From here. http://cobhomepages.cob.isu.edu/parkerkr/courses/CIS4480/assign/NORMAL_ans_complete.html    In each example (1NF) they are splits the table by REPEATING GROUPS and NON-REPEATING groups, but why they are adding PRIMARY-KEY Column in each REPEATING-GROUP. like `1. BRANCH (Branch#, Branch_Addr, (ISBN, Title, Author, Publisher, Num_copies))`

Now splits Table 1: `BRANCH-1 (Branch#, Branch_Addr)`

Table 2: `STOCKS-1 (Branch#, ISBN, Title, Author, Publisher, Num_copies)`
Why here `Branch#` also in STOCKS that is REPEATING-GROUP's table.